# How can I prevent my bot replying to every message in Slack?

Tags: c#, botframework

When an ms bot is integrated into slack it works fine when replying to direct messages however if the bot is added to a channel it replies to every single message posted into the channel, rather than just messages like **@myCustomBot 'this is my question'**.

Is it possible to filter incoming messages into the bot so it only looks to reply to channel messages directed specifically to the bot?

So far its using the basic controller actions you get for a new bot project:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(activity.CreateReply("hi there"));
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Logic would state you test the message string for the phrase "@myCustomBot" to decide if you respond or not

Comment: Good plan, however my concern here is you are coupling your bot implementation to how it then get's installed into a messaging channel. E.g. if you install into slack and call the bot installation something different, your code would fail. Similarly if you used in another app (skype as an example) - would you receive that same intro message?

Comment: Well, clearly it should know what its called - this would be in its configuration, so, you'd test for that..

Answer (score 2):

So the logic would be this:

1) Test for when people are addressing bot directly;

2) Differentiate that depending on the channel.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        if (activity.ChannelId === "slack") {
            if (activity.Text.ToLower().StartsWith("@myCustomBot") {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); //quit
            }
        }
        else if (activity.ChannelId === "facebook") {
            //similar check, and if true, then:
                //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        //otherwise, keep going:

        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(activity.CreateReply("hi there"));
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I made it slightly cleverer in the end and built the `activity.Text.ToLower().StartsWith("@myCustomBot")` check so it built the recipient name from `activity.Recipient.Name` hence it wasn't coupled in the c# code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I caused some ruckus in my Slack channel with the bot responding to every message haha